# how to set the xaxis in time interval, say 15min using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to set the xaxis in time interval 15minutes as:

```
'08:00', '08:15', '08:30', '08:45', '09:00', '09:15', '09:30', '09:45', '10:00','10:15', '10:30', '10:45','11:00'
```

So each one is a label in xaxis.

data is as follows:

```
data = [[0,1],[08:18,09:16],[10:18,10:52]]

x1 = data[:][1]

x2 = data[:][2]

y = data[:][0]
```

I want to use plot function to plot with data as above:

```
plt.plot(data[:][1], y,
         data[:][2], y)
```

After plotting, there should have two lines on the map. And the labels are in time interval of 15min.

Comment: What **exactly** is your data. Because `data = [[0,1],[08:18,09:16],[10:18,10:52]]` is not valid Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The given `data` is not valid in Python. It should be like `[["0","1"],["08:18","09:16"]]`.
2. Write a function to translate the time intervals into real number. (For understandablity to you, the code is not that pythonic.)

   ```
   def time_to_num(time_str):
       time_str = time_str.split(':')
           #check if time_str is valid here, then:
       num = 0
       num = int(time_str[0])
       if len(time_str) == 2:
           num += int(time_str[1])/60.0
       return num
   ```
3. Make it like `x1 = [time_to_num(item[1]) for item in data]`
4. Set the X axis lable as time interval with something like:

   ```
   #fig = matplotlib.plot...
   fig.set_xticks([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25])
   fig.set_xticklabels(['0:00', '0:15', '0:30', '0:45', '1:00', '1:15'])
   ```

Comment: You could also use `datetime` to do do the parsing for you.  You can then directly plot the `datetime` objects with maplotlib.  `setxticklabels` should only be used as a last resort, it de-couples your labels from your data.

Comment: @tcaswell Yup, it's a kinda dirty hack :-)

Comment: It works.:) Though setxticklabels here is a hack. I would like to use it.Thanks,Skyler and tcaswell.